# Why Ajax call is frozen during WebDriverWait (Selenium)

Tags: javascript, ajax, selenium

I am to test when an Ajax is called which would return a Not Found, an alert will be displayed.

The visibility of the alert is controlled by an 'ng-show' attribute. So `FindElement(By.Id())` should already find that element. I want to wait for the alert to be visible.

```
    protected IWebElement WaitForElement(string elementId)
    {
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(Host.TestWebDriver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
        return wait.Until(driver =>
        {
            var el = driver.FindElement(By.Id(elementId));
            if (el==null || !el.Displayed)
            {
                return null; // continue to wait if the element is not visible.
            }
            return el;
        });
    }
```

I was expecting that the `WebDriverWait` will wait for 2 minutes until the alert message is shown. But it appears my Ajax call never returns an error, and thus the JavaScript code to show the alert message has never been reached.

What should I do to let my Ajax complete while waiting?

---

Update:

Revised the `WaitForElement` above a bit:

```
    protected IWebElement WaitForElement(string elementId)
    {
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(Host.TestWebDriver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
        try
        {
            var el = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id(elementId)));
            return el;
        }
        catch (WebDriverTimeoutException ex)
        {
            // no element
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Still cannot make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The implicit wait in Selenium 2 might not work for Ajax elements. We recommend you to use any one of the following workaround to handle Ajax elements.

One approach is to use FluentWait and a Predicate available with Selenium2. The advantage of this approach is that element polling mechanism is configurable. The code example below waits for 1 second and polls for a textarea every 100 milliseconds.

```
 FluentWait<By> fluentWait = new FluentWait<By>(By.tagName("TEXTAREA"));
        fluentWait.pollingEvery(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        fluentWait.withTimeout(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        fluentWait.until(new Predicate<By>() {
            public boolean apply(By by) {
                try {
                    return browser.findElement(by).isDisplayed();
                } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        browser.findElement(By.tagName("TEXTAREA")).sendKeys("text to enter");
```

Another approach is to use ExpectedCondition and WebDriverWait strategy. The code below waits for 20 seconds or till the element is available, whichever is the earliest.

```
 public ExpectedCondition<WebElement> visibilityOfElementLocated(final By by) {
        return new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
          public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(by);
            return element.isDisplayed() ? element : null;
          }
        };
      }

      public void performSomeAction() {
        ..
        ..
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        WebElement element = wait.until(visibilityOfElementLocated(By.tagName("a")));
        ..        
      }
```

my particular adjustment of fluentWait in the way I use is in code:

```
public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator, WebDriver driver) {
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
//                .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

//                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
                .ignoring(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException.class);

        WebElement foo = wait.until(
                new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
                    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        return driver.findElement(locator);
                    }
                }
        );
        return foo;
    }
```

And the call will look like:

```
WebElement abracadabra = fluentWait(By.cssSelector('.elemSelector'));
```

For  hanling alerts and getting to know whether they are shown or not, I would recommend smth like:

```
 public boolean isAlertPresent(WebDriver driver) {

        boolean presentFlag;

        try {

            // Check the presence of alert
            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            // Alert present; set the flag
            presentFlag = true;
            // if present consume the alert
//            alert.accept();

        } catch (NoAlertPresentException ex) {
            // Alert not present
//            ex.printStackTrace();
            presentFlag = false;
        }

        return presentFlag;

    }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed input. But I am still having difficulty in understanding your line `driver.switchTo().alert();` The intellisense told me `switchTo()` instructs the driver to send future commands to a different frame or window. But how can I check the element in that new frame/window? How is your `.alert()` achieved?

Answer (score 0):

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
```

*Starting with Selenium 2.0 beta 1, there is built in support for handling popup dialog boxes. After you’ve triggered an action that opens a popup, you can access the alert with the string code above.*

Taken from [official selenium documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp)

Another group of actions- Moving Between Windows and Frames -  may be performed by

```
switchTo()
```

method.

Btw, here is a little bit modified wait for alert:

```
public void checkForAlert() {
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //exception handling
    }
}
```